# scraping a json response in scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been learning to scrape pages with scrapy.  Some of the data presented to me is in JSON format, and I have so far been unable to scrape a JSON page successfully.  I know it can be done (thanks to my only previous question and the helpful responses), but I just can't make it work.  I am wondering if a) anybody knows of an example of a successful scrapy script for JSON, or b) I could please have some pointers.

I have been using this page for some help:
 http://www.jroller.com/evans/entry/parsing_json_with_python , 
trying to scrape the page used as an example on it.

My spider runs but nothing is scraped.  I know I make mistakes, but I feel like I've changed every little aspect of the spyder at least once, and have now just made myself confused.

The basis of my spider (edited in response to suggestion below) is this:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from learnjson.items import learnjsonitems, Field
import json
import urllib2

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "jsonexample"
allowed_domains = ["googleapis.com"]
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8-10%20Broadway,%20London%20SW1H%200BG,%20United%20Kingdom&sensor=false'
)

def json_parse(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    latitude = jsonresponse["lat"]


    print item["lat"]
```

Taking the example of the page being scraped (not my data, just something to practice on), I have been trying to pull out, say, the street address and latitude/longitude, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed importing json.Add

import json in your code.

Also extarct and open your json file with urllib2 .It will work fine.
And you can append a code for json response like.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    ...   

    def parse(self, response):
         jsonresponse = json.loads(response)

         item = MyItem()
         item["firstName"] = jsonresponse["firstName"]             

         return item
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: also you can use json response to extract the data like class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    ...


    def parse(self, response):
         jsonresponse = json.loads(response)

         item = MyItem()
         item["firstName"] = jsonresponse["firstName"]             

         return item

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, however I have tried to do as you suggested, and it still scrapes nothing.  I have edited my post to show new spider - I am sure I am making a small/simple mistake, but jut cannot find it!

Comment: `response = json.loads(jsonResponse)` Replace `jsonResponse` with the json that you get